# Jenkins pipeline get NotSerializableException: WorkflowJob when using sh code

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a step in my pipeline which does this:

```
sh("shmig -m ${app_root}/${migration_folder} -t mysql -H $mysql_server -l $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -d $schema up")
```

It works fine but sometime I get this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
```

Nothing change between build and I don't understand this error.

Have you any idea ?

For more information about the call, it is done like this:

```
node('docker') {
    step('shmig') {
       smhig()
    }
} 

def smhig() {
   ...
   sh("shmig -m ${app_root}/${migration_folder} -t mysql -H $mysql_server -l $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -d $schema up")
}
```

Comment: That is definitely a tough one. Do you use the `properties` step? This looks like it isn't even caused by the pipeline itself, and more from some plugins or whatever is genrating the job itself (multibranch? organization folder? Does it still happen if the only thing in the build file is a `sleep(1)`?

Comment: This job come from a multi branch pipeline indeed. I use the step property yes and no it’s not happened when I do a sleep(1)

Comment: I assume the code given will not reproduce the error? Somewhere in your pipeline you must be using a class which is not serializable. Try to get something smaller which reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any variable declarations/assignments before that 'sh("shmig -m ...)' line? I used to face the same error and now it is gone after I replaced all the variable declarations from

> myVar = myVal

to

> def myVar = myVal

Not sure if that can help but I hope so.